# Alignment inside in-line $$ math environment

Tags: math-mode, equations, alignment, inline, text-manipulation

I would like to be able to use (equation) alignment inside a simple in-line `$...$` environment.

Of course, normally nobody does this, when this is properly done with the standalone equation environments. However, some text editors support limited simple LaTeX rendering, and they may only support the basic in-line math environment `$...$` and not recognise more complex (standard) environments like `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`. So it would be really nice and useful if this can be done somehow.

In my case, I am specifically using [stackedit.io](https://stackedit.io). It does not recognise the `equation` environment, just `$$` apparently.

Comment: I wonder what kind of solution you expect. If you are working with a text editor with only simple latex rendering (no environments), it is highly likely that any somewhat sophisticated solution will not be recognized either. So I believe you should at least give some indication of your software environment.

Comment: Yes -- updated.

Comment: There is nothing that prevents you from using, for example, `aligned` inside of a `$...$` math environment.

Comment: Looks like your use case is a Markdown editor that (very, very) probably uses MathJax or KaTeX but not 'real' TeX or LaTeX to render maths. The set of commands supported by MathJax and KaTeX is usually a subset of what TeX allows you to do (with packages). And since MathJax and KaTeX aren't TeX, questions about them are usually off-topic here. They can be asked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathjax for example.

Comment: slightly oddly despite suggesting use with stackexchange it uses katex rather than mathjax, however that does allow `$\begin{aligned} a&=b\\...\end{aligned}$`